# Write the contents of a file(handle) to a different filehandle

Tags: perl

How can I write the contents of one file/filehandle to another? I know I could open the file, slurp the input into a variable than print the variable to the second filehandle, but I was wondering if there was a nicer/library solution available, that perhaps also handles large files (and doesn't load the entire file into memory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File::Copy supports copying not only by name, [but by filehandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html):

```
use File::Copy qw(copy);

copy(FILE_IN, FILE_OUT);
```

where FILE_IN and FILE_OUT are filehandles opened for reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this one does not load entire file to a memory:

```
open F, "file1" or die "Error reading file1";
open G, ">file2" or die "Error writing file2";

print G while <F>;

close F;
close G;
```

And if you want to copy a file while not reading it, use:

```
use File::Copy;

copy("file1","file2") or die "Error: $!";
```

But please not that above [will not preserve file's permissions](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html). If you want to preserve them, use it as an alias - invoking 'copy' as 'cp' makes it behave like shell command 'cp':

```
use File::Copy "cp"

cp("file1", "file2") or die "Error: $!";
```

Finally, although it's not very portable solution, you can always just invoke shell:

```
`cp file1 file2`;
```